# how do I create a modal view in ionic 2?

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic2

The documentation shows you how to open the modal, but isn't clear on what kind of page you're supposed to be passing to the open() method

example from docs:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

 }

 presentContactModal() {
   let contactModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ContactUs);
   contactModal.present();
 }
```

It isn't clear how where the 'ContactUs' object comes from, there is no import for it. 
This example linked to here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Comment: Try to avoid example code from documentation. Always try to see example from the [demo source](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/src/pages/modals/basic) or [ionic-conference-app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app)
Because their documentation change everyday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(...)
class HomePage {

    constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {    }
    presentContactModal() {
         let contactModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ContactUs);
         contactModal.present();
    }    
}
```

///////////////below is the Contact us component which is define with in Homepage

```
@Component(...)
class ContactUs {

   constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {

   }

   dismiss() {
     this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
   }
}
```

Comment: were to place the template for the contact us page @Nitin Walia

Comment: @component({
  templateUrl: 'contactUs.html'
})

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to generate a modal content page:

```
ionic g ModalPage
```

Then you have to open modal-content.module.ts if the command creates this file, you have to change

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forChild(ModalPage),
  ],
```

TO :

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(ModalPage),
  ],
```

Then you have to add some html for the modal structure:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      GO OUT
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()">
        <span ion-text color="primary" showWhen="ios">Cancel</span>
        <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android,windows"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <p> This is a modal test!!!! </p>
</ion-content>
```

Then you have to import in the declarations and entryComponents of the app module.

```
import { ModalPage } from '../pages/modal-page/modal-page';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    Main,
    ModalPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ModalPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Device,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
```

Then in the page you want to execute the modal you have to add a function to the element you want to use to fire it.

```
<div full large class="button-el btn-goOut" (tap)="openModal()">
```

In the page you want to use the modal you have to import :

```
 import { ModalPage } from '../modal-page/modal-page'
```

Important: this element should not be in the constructor, to call the modal you only have to do like this:

```
openModal(){
      let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
      modal.present();
  }
```

Comment: hey there is no such command as `ionic g ModalPage`.
can i use `ionic g page Modelpage` and then use that page as model.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a working example [here in the docs repository](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/modals/basic/pages.ts).

> It isn't clear how where the 'ContactUs' object comes from, there is
>   no import for it.

`ContactUs` is just another page, you can use any page from your app to create a modal with it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, Platform, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class BasicPage {
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) { }

  openModal(characterNum) {

    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalContentPage, characterNum);
    modal.present();
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Description
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()">
        <span ion-text color="primary" showWhen="ios">Cancel</span>
        <ion-icon name="md-close" showWhen="android, windows"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="{{character.image}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{character.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{character.quote}}</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of character['items']">
        {{item.title}}
        <ion-note item-right>
          {{item.note}}
        </ion-note>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
`
})
export class ModalContentPage {
  character;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public params: NavParams,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController
  ) {
    var characters = [
      {
        name: 'Gollum',
        quote: 'Sneaky little hobbitses!',
        image: 'assets/img/avatar-gollum.jpg',
        items: [
          { title: 'Race', note: 'Hobbit' },
          { title: 'Culture', note: 'River Folk' },
          { title: 'Alter Ego', note: 'Smeagol' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Frodo',
        quote: 'Go back, Sam! I\'m going to Mordor alone!',
        image: 'assets/img/avatar-frodo.jpg',
        items: [
          { title: 'Race', note: 'Hobbit' },
          { title: 'Culture', note: 'Shire Folk' },
          { title: 'Weapon', note: 'Sting' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Samwise Gamgee',
        quote: 'What we need is a few good taters.',
        image: 'assets/img/avatar-samwise.jpg',
        items: [
          { title: 'Race', note: 'Hobbit' },
          { title: 'Culture', note: 'Shire Folk' },
          { title: 'Nickname', note: 'Sam' }
        ]
      }
    ];
    this.character = characters[this.params.get('charNum')];
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

In the example below, `ModalContentPage` is used to create the modal. Please notice that it's recommended to include just one component per file, so ideally you'd create the page to use as a modal in a different file.

Comment: I looked at the repository you linked to and am more confused. I'm going to try to find a more simple example of a modal. There's too much going on there and the simple steps aren't clear.